# MySQLi stmt num_rows returns 0 on server. On wamp works just fine

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code that is trouble

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
```

Comment: (Please go read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks before asking your next question, thank you.)

Comment: what are you trying to do? mention the problem and full code

Comment: The code isn't likely to blame when the exact same snippet works on the local setup. You didn't post enough debugging details (input values, db structure and content samples; see [mcve]) to make this answerable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?');
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
```

You were closing wrongly one bracket and had an extra unnecessary curly bracket.

Comment: (Chances are OP just omitted the `if` when posting the excerpt.)